# how to use count in for each in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, count

```
  <h3>Top Members</h3>
    <div class ="name">
    <div class="col-md-2" id="content">
    <?php $i=0; ?>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <h5><a href="#"<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></a>{{ $post->user->name }} </h5>
    @endforeach
```

Here is my code , I want to select top 5 from database

Answer (score 0):

In you controller where you get the `$posts` var instead of

```
Post::orderBy('created_at','asc')->get();
```

use something like

```
Post::orderBy('created_at','asc')->take(5)->get();
```

**NOTE:** thi is only an assumtion how you call your posts

Answer (score 0):

You can use like that

```
Post::all()->take(5)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get count of number of records in table using model

```
$count = ModelName::count();
```

For top 5 records

```
ModelName::all()->take(5)->get();
```

For paginatation

```
$data= ModelName::paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Fetch the 5 rows from the database by writing the select query with limit and then loop those columns in view page.

In Controller:

public function post_lists(){
$posts=\DB::table('posts_table')->limit(5)->orderby('postid','desc')->get();
return view('posts', compact('posts'));
}

In View page:

<h3>Top Members</h3>
    <div class ="name">
    <div class="col-md-2" id="content">
    <?php $i=0; ?>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <h5><a href="#"<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></a>{{ $post->user->name }} </h5>
    @endforeach
```